# Grass using hair system stops working when I come to render, it just flattens

Tags: particles, hair

As it says in the title when I come to render my scene, the hair system just stops working and looks nothing like the material preview or viewport render.

Not really sure whats causing it, I have another patch of grass in a pot and that works fine, and I can't seem to see any difference in settings.

The only thing I could find it when I turned off children there was no hair at all, the parents didn't render. Also, when I turn on virtual parents it seems to work but with very few hairs and odd shape, so it doesn't fix the problem at all.

I am quite new to particle systems so there could be an incredibly simple fix that I am missing.

Here's the file:

[image]

[image: What's seen when rendering]

[image: The grass in material preview]

[image: Hair settings]

Comment: please provide blend file

Comment: Are you using GPU Compute to render in Cycles?

Comment: @Chris I've not really used blender stack exchange before, but I found blend exchange; is that how to do it. Doesn't seem to be working though, says "There was an internal error attempting to complete your request."

Comment: @ZargulTheWizard yes I am

Comment: @TtForge: yes, i meant https://blend-exchange.com/. just follow instructions. for me it worked always....but...maybe your blend file is too big?

Comment: @TtForge Yeah, blend-exchange.com or pasteall.org are blender.stackexchange.com community’s accepted system of file transfer on the forum. Anyway, what GPU do you have? Is the same problem present in a CPU render or in EEVEE?

Comment: @Chris I uploaded the file, I had to unpack the image textures I was using it was too big.

Comment: @ZargulTheWizard It doesn't change with either eevee or CPU compute, and I have a GTX 1080ti.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am stupid and had a modifier that was turned off in viewport but on for render, I for some very irritating reason didn't check until now.

Comment: Happens :)  Glad you were able to fix your issue.  You might include a screenshot of the problematic modifier stack just in case anyone searches with the same problem.